# View data in Google Spreadsheet, where data comes outside

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm developing a web application that handles some kind of query engines. It means my application generates a result of a query, and its user can view it on the web application.

What I'd like to do is to help the user open the result in Google Spreadsheet. For instance, when a user is viewing the result on the web app and clicks the button named "*Open this data in Google Spreadsheet*", the data is shown in Spreadsheet.

- Is it possible to develop such a feature in a web application?
- Where can I get the information to develop it?

Any suggestions would be welcomed!

Comment: Are you talking about a general web application or a Google Apps Script Web app? Do you want to open data that is already in a spreadsheet or do you want to export the data from the result set to a spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm refering to a general web application, and I'd like to export the web application's data into a spreadsheet. I sometimes use Google's BigQuery, and it enables us to show data in Google SpreadSheet. Both are their services though, but I wonder we can do the same thing in a general web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do in the code that is triggered by "*Open this data in Google Spreadsheet*" is to actually create the document **IN** Google Spreadsheet and then redirect the user to the document you just created.

You need do a couple of things.

1. Get authorization from the user to actually access his Google Spreadsheet account.
2. Create the document.
3. Redirect the user to it.

Documentation for [1] can be found at https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing. Documentation for [2] and [3] can be found at https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/dotnet (for C#, other languages are available)

Comment: Thank you for the point to the documents! I'll develop my app according to them.